# How to make a request in SolrCloud?

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I have a Node.js app and I used to have a standalone Solr but then our company decided to use SolrCloud to provide failover.

In the standalone Solr I had only the one server with it and I had all my requests like: `http://solr_server:8983/solr/mycore/select?indent=on&q=*:*&wt=json` so all requests led to the same server all the time.

But now I have 3 different instances with 1 ZooKeeper and 1 Solr node on each of them and my requests look like this: `http://solr_server_1:8983/solr/mycollection/select?q=*:*`
And now the question: what if the `solr_server_1` will go down? How can I still get my results? How can I handle requests in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing this manually: You'll have to catch the exception when the connection fails, and then retry the next server in your list.

```
let servers = ['ip1:8983', 'ip2:8983', 'ip3:8983']
```

If you're using a library that supports Zookeeper (i.e. it connects to zookeeper to find out what the live nodes are), you give the client a list of zookeeper nodes and lets it figure out the rest. [node-solr-smart-client](https://github.com/jijordre/node-solr-smart-client) is a client that supports Zookeeper as well.

```
options = {
    zkConnectionString: 'ip1:2181,ip2:2181,ip3:2181',
    // etc.
}

solrSmartClient.createClient('my_solr_collection', options, function (err, solrClient) {
```

Comment: What if I create an "A" record and point it on multiple IPs? For example: `solr.mysite.com --- xxx.xxx.xxx.1` and `solr.mysite.com --- xxx.xxx.xxx.2` and just use this DNS. Will this work?

Comment: You probably want a dedicated load balancer and not just round robin DNS in that case, so that you can add and remove nodes (and not expose internal information about your Solr cluster externally). haproxy can be suitable as a LB.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and comment! In my case I used a DNS service that handle requests to an IP and if it doesn't response switch to another IP.